# Lua function in Redis - error attempt to compare nil with number

Tags: redis, lua, redis-cluster

I've a Redis cluster v7.x with 3 masters each having a slave.
I've defined a Lua function as following:

```
local keyGet = redis.call('GET', timeSlotKey)

local currentValue = 0
if keyGet ~= nil then
    currentValue = tonumber(keyGet)
else
    currentValue = 0
end

redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, currentValue)
if currentValue < 5 then
    redis.call('INCR', timeSlotKey)
    redis.call('EXPIRE', timeSlotKey, expiryDuration)
    return 1
else
    return 0
end
```

When I call the function from command line it throws an error:

`attempt to compare nil with number` at line `if currentValue < 5 then`

**What is the issue here? How to use the return value of GET call from the Redis?**

Comment: I don't know what redis is but from your code it's clear that the only way this error would come is if `keyGet` is not `nil` but it's also not a number. Maybe simply check what value it actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after trying other things, I added

`redis.setresp(3)`

inside the lua function and it is working now.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that currentValue is set to nil in the call to tonumber(keyGet).

From the lua manual for tonumber:

> Tries to convert its argument to a number. If the argument is already a number or a string convertible to a number, then tonumber returns this number; otherwise, it returns nil.

So, even though keyGet is not nil, whatever it is, it is still not convertible into a number.

Add a line to log the value of keyGet after local keyGet = redis.call(...)

redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, keyGet)

Hopefully, that will tell you why the value of keyGet isn't working with tonumber.

Comment: Should wrap to_number with a function returning a default value?